# Unknown error in code when trying to address a pointer to memory

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to clarify something. Below are what I'm supposed to do:

```
void key_print1(Key key);
```

Print a key, key –> key1 and then key–> key2

From my understanding, I'm creating a pointer variable called key that is pointing to the memory address of key1, and then it points to the memory address of key2. I don't understand why there's an error in my code? Am I understanding the instructions wrong?

```
void key_print1(Key key) {
    Key key1;
    Key key2;
    Key* key = &key1;
//    Key* key = &key2;
    printf("%p", key);
```

```
typedef float* Data;
typedef char* Key1;
typedef int Key2;
typedef struct {
    Key1 key1;
    Key1 key2;
} Key_struct;
typedef Key_struct* Key;
void key_print1(Key key);
```

Comment: You can't have multiple variables with the same name in the same scope. In `key_print`, you have **three** variables named `key` (one passed in as a parameter, two more declared in code). How is the compiler supposed to know which one of the three you want to print out using `printf()`? Also, there is no `key1` or `key2` anywhere in the code you've posted prior to your trying to grab a reference to them. Learn to read the code coming out of your keyboard, and make sure it makes sense.

Comment: Also, if you're not sure that you understand your assignment, you should be asking your instructor. They're the one who knows exactly what task you were given, and are in the best position to know if you've got it right or not. They're also being paid to answer your questions about your lessons.

Comment: @Ken White Even if I comment out one line with the key variable, it still shows the error. And key1 and key2 are defined in the constructor. Could it be something related to the struct I defined?

Comment: You keep saying *shows the error*, but there is no error message in your question. And as I said, you have **three** with the same name, so commenting out one still leaves **two**. You **can't have more than one with the same name in the same scope**, as I said in my first sentence in my first comment above. Also, don't describe what's somewhere else in your code. Instead, post a [mre] that can be copied and pasted into a code editor, compiled, and run, and will demonstrate the issue.

Comment: ok, sorry, I'm quite new to this. 
I edited the code in the question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. The post still mentions *error*, without including the error message or a description of an error. Your code now is incomplete, and you've still not provided a [mre] that demonstrates the issue; you've just posted bits of it out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want to do, but I see some big mistakes.

First, you're redefining key with a different type, which is an error. Indeed, the variable key given in the parameter is of type `Key`, but `Key* key = &key1;` redefines it as `*Key`, which is a different type. Actually, you can't even redefine a variable with the same type: `int a = 1`; and then `int a = 2` is an error, but `int a = 1;` and then `a = 2` is correct.

Then, what are `key1` and `key2`? You're using undefined variables, which is an error.A
Furthermore, you should really clarify what `key1` and `key2` are because right now it is quite hard to understand what you want to do.

UPDATE :

Base on the code you added, I understant that you `key_print1` functions should display `key1` and `key2` of `Key` structure. `key1` and `key2` are attributes of key so you can get them with `key->key1` and `key->key2`.
So basicly, if you want to print `key->key1` and then `key->key2` you can write

```c
printf("%s\n", key->key1);
printf("%d\n", key->key2);
```

Here, `%s` is used to print a `char *`, `%d` to print an `int` and `\n`to print a newline after each call to printf.

Comment: key1 is a character pointer, it is for the String in key type and key2 is an integer for the key type. The key type will be later used as a matrix structure. Also, thank you, the other example with int was helpful to see.

Comment: Yes I saw your update so I updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much!